# Error in converting NSArray to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray

I have NSArray with NSDictionaries inside. I need to post JSON. So I tried to make post request with NSURLConnection, but I'm given an error (bad url).
I convert NSArray such direction:

```
NSData *dishesData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dishes options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *dishesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dishesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then paste it to NSString with request.

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@", SERVER_ADDRESS, ACTION, ORDER_ACTION, ORDER_NAME, name, ORDER_EMAIL, email, ORDER_PHONE, phone, ORDER_DELIVERY, delivery, ORDER_ADDRESS, address, ORDER_DISHES, dishesString];
```

Then I log 1st time:

```
2013-09-17 20:01:13.926 Eda.by[3088:c07] http://eda.by/api.php?act=order&name=Тимур&email=bernikowich@testemail2.com&phone=+375296802009&delivery=1&address=Тестовый адрес!&dish=[
  {
    "count" : 2,
    "id" : 86
  }
]
```

If I'll try to post this I'll get error "bad url".
Thats why I try to encode this by:

```
requestString = [requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

After that I get such logs:

```
http://eda.by/api.php?act=order&name=%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80&email=bernikowich@testemail2.com&phone=+375296802009&delivery=1&address=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81!&dish=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22count%22%20:%202,%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20:%2086%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D
```

It sends well, but data are wrong and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert an NSDictionary to a JSON string with this code:

```
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

then create an NSData object:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: But I need to convert NSAArray, not NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "POST", you need to add json as a body of request. eq:

```
[request setHTTPBody:(NSData *)];
```